# Concat files based on MVC Area

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, gulp

I'm building an MVC application, which is making use of Areas. So I've got a folder structure as follows:

```
Areas/
  AreaOne/
    Views/
      About/
        ScriptOne.js
        ScriptTwo.js
        Index.cshtml
      Home/
        ScriptThree.js
        ScriptFour.js
        Index.cshtml
  AreaTwo
    Views/...
```

I'd like to bundle the JavaScript files within the individual page's folder within the View folder.

E.g. `ScriptOne.js, ScriptTwo.js` should be bundled into `About.js` and output into a seperate folder like:

```
js/
  Areas/
    AreaOne/
      About.js
      Home.js
```

I'm able to grab the files, however it will grab all .js files under Areas.

```
gulp.src('./Areas/**/*.js')

Areas\AreaOne\Views\About\ScriptOne.js
Areas\AreaOne\Views\About\ScriptTwo.js
Areas\AreaOne\Views\Home\ScriptThree.js
Areas\AreaOne\Views\Home\ScriptFour.js
```

If I concat this I'll end up with a single .js file. However I'd like `About.js` and `Home.js`

If I can achieve the above in theory I can use the following (but i'm unsure how to get the appropriate area name:

```
pipe(gulp.dest('./js/Areas/...AREA NAME GOES HERE.../'))
```

I'm trying to avoid manual concatenation of files.. like so..

```
gulp.src(['./Areas/AreaOne/Views/About/ScriptOne.js', './Areas/AreaOne/Views/About/ScriptTwo.js'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the most succinct way but it works and it's fairly simple.

I use Glob to get the file names within the Areas.

I then add the view paths to a JavaScript object (this works like a set, it prevents duplicates), I also add the name of the view folder as this will be the output file name.

I use gulp.src with the distinct view folder names to collect all of the Javascript files within the individual view folder and then concat them, and finally if it's a release build the files get ugilfied.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('process-areas-js', function () {

    glob('./Areas/**/*.js*', null, function (er, files) {
        var distinctAreaPaths = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            var filePath = path.dirname(files[i]).replace(/\./g, "");
            var viewFolderName = path.basename(filePath);

            distinctAreaPaths[filePath] = viewFolderName;
        }

        for (distinctPath in distinctAreaPaths) {            
            var concatName = distinctAreaPaths[distinctPath] + ".js";
            var destination = './js' + path.dirname(distinctPath);
            var sourceGlob = "." + distinctPath + "/*.js";

            var pipeline = gulp.src(sourceGlob)
                .pipe(concat(concatName))

            uglifyOnRelease(pipeline)
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));                            
        }
    });    
});

gulp.task('default', ['process-areas-js']);

function uglifyOnRelease(pipeline) {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'Release' || process.env.NODE_ENV == null ? pipeline.pipe(uglify()) : pipeline;
}
```